# What is the sum of this expected value? (German Tank Problem)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to prove certain results in this article by Roger Johnson [Estimating the size of a population](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.385.5463&rank=1). In particular, I want to prove the variance he obtains for his four measures $\hat N_i$.

For the variables $X_{(i)}$ when $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, I can prove the following:

$$E(X_{(i)})=\frac{i(N+1)}{n+1}$$

$$Var(X_{(i)})=\frac{i(n-i+1)(N-n)(N+1)}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}$$

I want to calculate the variance of certains sums of $X_{(i)}$ and $X_{(j)}$. Because these variables are not independent, I have to calculate the covariance.

I have :

$$P(X_{(A)}=i \cap X_{(B)}=j)=\frac{{i-1 \choose A-1}{N-j \choose n-B}{j-i-1 \choose B-A-1}}{{N\choose n}}$$

I know that this sum is correct because the sums of the above probabilities must sum to 1:

$$\frac{1}{N\choose n}\sum_{i=A}^{N-n+A} {i-1 \choose A-1}\sum_{j=B-A+i}^{N-n+B} {N-j \choose n-B}{j-i-1 \choose B-A-1}=1$$

What I want to know is the value of this sum:

$$E(X_{(A)}\cdot X_{(B)}) = \frac{1}{N\choose n}\sum_{i=A}^{N-n+A}i {i-1 \choose A-1}\sum_{j=B-A+i}^{N-n+B}j {N-j \choose n-B}{j-i-1 \choose B-A-1}$$